Inverting pin value in physical constraints (Gowin EDA)
I've recently bought a Tang Mega 138k Pro fpga board. it contains some peripherals (switches, led, ...) that are active low. Is there any way to invert the pin in physical constraints file so i don't need to change hdl designs?
I tried to read the docs and user guide but i can't find anything about this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are no constraints you're seeking for, and it's likely it doesn't exist anywhere else. Only clock constraints has waveform inversion constraint, but not general purpose I/O.
If your design was written with other hardware in mind, like the one that requires active high levels, then you should make a top-level module, wrapping up existing stuff and adapting it to changed conditions. Constraints aren't the right tool here.
